# How to make $N_0$ the subject in $N_0=2^{N_0}\varepsilon\,?$

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

[image]
I am assuming the next step is that $N_0$ is made the subject in $N_0=2^{N_0}\varepsilon$.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the subject". Are you asking for how to solve that equation? If so, I'll just say that's asking for the wrong thing. You *should* be thinking about how to solve the inequality $\frac{n^2}{2^n} < \epsilon$. But even then your goal is not to find the exact solution set of that inequality, instead you only need to find some $N_0$ so that each $n > N_0$ is in the solution set.

Comment: @LeeMosher: To “make $x$ the subject” is an expression that seems to be common in British schools: https://thirdspacelearning.com/gcse-maths/algebra/make-x-the-subject/

Comment: @HansLundmark: That's interesting! In that language, I would say that the goal is not to "make $x$ the subject" of the equation, but instead to "make $x$ the subject" of the inequality.

Comment: See [why image cannot be used for explaining my maths problem](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem) on Meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the proof wants to say that

$$
\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert
= \left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} \right\rvert
= \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} < \frac{n^2}{2^n}.
$$

Every step in this chain of equations (and one inequality) is true for all $n$ except the middle step:

$$ \left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} \right\rvert = \frac{n^2-1}{2^n}.  $$

This is false when $n = 0.$ If we're not limited to integer values of $n,$
the equation is false whenever $-1 < n < 1.$

But if $n > 1$ then all the equations so far are true. So it's good enough to say
$n > 1$ at this point.

I'm not sure why $N_0$ has been mentioned at all so early in the proof;
the $N_0$ that is part of the definition of a limit as $n \to \infty$
is needed when we want to show that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \varepsilon,
$$
but all we have required so far is that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \frac{n^2}{2^n}.
$$

Now, how can knowing
$\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \frac{n^2}{2^n}$
have anything to do with proving that
$\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \varepsilon,$
which is what you need?
It's simple: if you can show that
$\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \frac{n^2}{2^n}$
and you can show that
$\frac{n^2}{2^n} < \varepsilon$
then you will have shown that
$$
\left\lvert \frac{n^2-1}{2^n} - 0 \right\rvert < \varepsilon.
$$

In a delta-epsilon proof you should never, ever, ever **need** to find the exact value of a variable that makes some expression exactly equal to $\varepsilon.$
All you need for the proof is an inequality.
In this case,
$$\frac{n^2}{2^n} < \varepsilon. $$

Find **a** value of $N_0$ so that $\frac{n^2}{2^n} < \varepsilon$
whenever $n > N_0$. It doesn't have to be the "best" or "exact" value of $N_0,$
just **a** value of $N_0$ that works. If your value of $N_0$ happens to be a little larger than your classmate's answer or the teacher's answer,
you still have a valid proof as long as you correctly showed the necessary inequality.

After all, by setting yourself up to require $N_0$ to be so large that it guarantees that
$$\frac{n^2}{2^n} < \varepsilon$$
instead of merely requiring it to be large enough so that
$$\frac{n^2 - 1}{2^n} < \varepsilon,$$
you have already put a requirement on $N_0$ that may make it larger than the very minimum value that was needed for the proof.
This is OK precisely because finding the "minimum value" of $N_0$
was never a requirement for the proof.

Answer (score 0):

For $n>16$, we have $n^2-1<2^{\frac{n}{2}}$ thus $\left|\dfrac{n^2-1}{2^n} \right|=\dfrac{n^2-1}{2^n}< \dfrac{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}{2^n}=\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}},$ and we have $\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, so from squeeze theorem, $\lim \dfrac{n^2-1}{2^n} =0.$

If you want to use $\epsilon-$ arguement, let $\epsilon\in (0,1)$ and $N_0$ be a natural number larger than $-2\log_2 \epsilon$ and $16$. (e.g. $N_0:=[-2\log_2 \epsilon]+16.$)

Then for $n\geqq N_0$,
$$
\left|\dfrac{n^2-1}{2^n}-0 \right|
<\dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{n}{2}}}
\leqq \dfrac{1}{2^{\frac{N_0}{2}}}
\leqq \epsilon.
$$